# How can I get and process a new S3 file for every iteration of an mrjob mapper?

Tags: python, emr, mrjob

I have a log file of status_changes, each one of which has a driver_id, timestamp, and duration. Using driver_id and timestamp, I want to fetch the appropriate GPS log from S3. These GPS logs are stored in an S3 bucket in the form bucket_name/yyyy/mm/dd/driver_id.log.

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
class Mileage(MRJob):

    def get_s3_gpslog_path(self, driver_id, occurred_at, status):
        s3_path = "s3://gps_logs/{yyyy}/{mm}/{dd}/{driver_id}.log"
        s3_path = s3_path.format(yyyy=occurred_at.year,
                                 mm=occurred_at.month,
                                 dd=occurred_at.day,
                                 driver_id=driver_id)
        return s3_path

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        line = ast.literal_eval(line)
        driver_id = line['driverId']
        occurred_at = line['timestamp']
        status = line['status']
        s3_path = self.get_s3_gpslog_path(driver_id, occurred_at, status)
        # ^^ How do I fetch this file and read it?
        distance = calculate_distance_from_gps_log(s3_path, occurred_at, status)

        yield status, distance


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Mileage.run()
```

And from the command line I run it with the status_change log file as input:
    $ python mileage.py status_changes.log

My question is: How do I actually fetch that GPS log, given the S3 URI string I have constructed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [S3Filesystem](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/runners-emr.html#s3-utilities) that is part of mrjob. You may also use [boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/)'s S3 utility within your script. You will likely need to hardcode (or parse from Hadoop configuration in each node) the (secret) access key. However, what the mapper is doing may be a bit too much, potentially making excessive requests to get S3 resources. You might be able to rewrite the MapReduce algorithm to do the join in a less resource-intensive way by streaming in the GPS logs along with the other logs.